# Cannot use module "dotenv" in my preload.js even if I have it in my dependencies

Tags: javascript, electron, dependencies, dotenv, npm-shrinkwrap

I have just started using Electron.

This is the start of my `preload.js`:

```js
const { contextBridge } = require('electron');
require('dotenv').config();
// ...
```

When I used `npm start`, the app started normally, except that the preload.js didn't do anything. I opened the developer tools and saw this error:

```
Error: module not found: dotenv
    at preloadRequire (...)
...
```

Then I checked my `npm-shrinkwrap.json`:

```json
"devDependencies": {
    // ...
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "electron": "^22.1.0"
}
```

Well, it sure had `dotenv`.

So, how can I make `preload.js` be able to use `dotenv`?

Comment: See the warning in the [official Electron documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload#augmenting-the-renderer-with-a-preload-script). Sandboxing could be the cause of your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [Alexander Leithner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6786876/alexander-leithner), I worked out the problem.

In the [documentation](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox), it says the 'sandbox' limits what I can 'require' from preload.js; so to disable it, set `sandbox: false` or `nodeIntegration: true` in `webPreferences` in the `BrowserWindow` options.

### Example

```js
app.whenReady().then(() => {
  const win = new BrowserWindow({
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true
    }
  })
  win.loadURL('https://google.com')
})
```